# How to pass custom column names to pandas dataframe with Latin1 character encoding?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, character-encoding

## Goal

I have multiple csv files with latin1 encoding. I want to load them into dataframes with **custom colum names**, concatenate them, and write them to a new large latin1 csv file that I then import into MSSQL.

## Issue

Pandas reads & writes the data just fine, and MSSQL loads the data fine as well. However, when I import the file with MSSQL, column names are removed because of "invalid characters": [image: MSSQL error message when loading csv as flat file]

**How can I make sure not only the data, but also the custom column names are encoded correctly? I have tried passing column names with `str.encode(encoding='latin1')`, to no avail.**

## Code

```
import os
import pandas as pd 

cols =  ["name", "name2", "etc"]

dfs = []
for folder in dir:
    root, _, files = next(os.walk(path_to_dir))
    dfs += [pd.read_csv(path_to_dir, names=cols, encoding='latin1') for file in files]

pd.concat(dfs).to_csv(path_to_file, index=False, encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [`unidecode`](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) to [`pandas.DataFrame.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) to get rid of punctuation and/or symbols.

Try this :

```
#pip install unidecode
from unidecode import unidecode

df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.columns = list(map(lambda x: unidecode(x), df.columns))
df.to_csv(path_to_file, index=False, encoding='latin1')
```

Comment: I tried this, but MSSQL still gives me the same error when trying to load in the csv (see edited question).

Comment: Can you `print(df.columns)` and add it to your question as well ?

Comment: The columns look the same before and after using `unidecode`. It happens no matter what strings I use, even `["col1","col2",...]` will do it.

Comment: Have you checked if there is any duplicated column names ?  `print(df.columns.duplicated().any())`

Comment: yep... :/ there aren't any.

Comment: [MSSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/column-name-limitations?view=sql-server-ver16) seems to not tolerate whitespaces, can you try `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("\s+", "_", regex=True)`

Comment: Thanks for all the effort! But there are no whitespaces in my column names, only underscores.